# Всплывающее один раз окно

Tags: php, javascript

Суть такова - есть банер , который прилеплен к низу страницы и всегда остаётся там, на нём же есть кнопочка закрытия.

Вопрос - как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопочку закрыть банер в течении дня больше не открывался (записывать в куки?)? Я пытался на js сделать но не справился, подскажите.
Код банера

```
#sticky-footer {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ECF1EF;
    background: #151715;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }
#sticky-footer a {
    font: normal 18px Trebuchet MS;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
#close {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url('close.png') top no-repeat;
    border: none;
    margin: 3px 0 0 15px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
    //settings
    var fadeSpeed = 200, fadeTo = 0.5, topDistance = 30;
    var sibar = function() { $('#sticky-footer').fadeTo(fadeSpeed,1); }, stbar = function() { $('#sticky-footer').fadeTo(fadeSpeed,fadeTo); };
    var inside = false;
    //do
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        position = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(position > topDistance && !inside) {
            //add mouseover events
            stbar();
            $('#sticky-footer').bind('mouseenter',sibar);
            $('#sticky-footer').bind('mouseleave',stbar);
            inside = true;
        }
    });
    //close
    $('#close').live('click', function(event) {
        $('#sticky-footer').toggle('show');
    });
    })();
});
</script>
<div id="sticky-footer">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">Форум помощи начинающим сайтостроителям</a>
    <span id="close"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. live() нет в jquery больше и достаточно давно.
 2. есть библиотеки для работы с куками, но я бы лучше использовал библиотеку для local storage. далее все просто - проверяем ключ при загрузке страницы и убираем банер. 
 3. если страничка подгружается с php то наверное лучше всего действительно просто не передавать баннер - в таком случае отправьте запрос через ajax при закрытии и запишите в сессию. при генерации страницы проверяйте.
 4. следите за речью, мы не на зоне.

Comment: Совсем не понял про 4 пункт, какое зоновское слово я сказал?

Comment: @eicto ах вы про бубен, вы никогда не слышали выражение "Скакал с бубном вокруг компьютера"? Это же ведь разговорный сленг програмистов

Comment: только применяете вы его не в тему :) это обычно относится к администрированию и чаще к железу. А у вас звучит как бубен -> голова (лицо). Вообще в плясках с бубном важен не сам бубен а скорее пляска - ритуал. Например в результате какого-то бага в системе толи X11 толи gdm, мне приходилось при старте компа переключаться в консоль, запускать Xorg :1, потом опять переключаться, запускать service gdm restart и прибивать X11 во втором экране, чего это было я так и не разобрался, потом само пропало.

Answer (score 2):

Для твоей задачи подойдет  `jquery cookie` вот [тут](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) все понятно: в начале проверяешь есть ли кука, например `'close'`  если есть то  `$('#sticky-footer').toggle('hiden);`
иначе показать и при клике на закрытие объявляешь куку

```
// так можно установить новые кукисы или переписать значения у уже существующих:
$.cookie('close', '3234342'); //в качестве значения можно устонавить время и проверять прошли ли сутки
```

Comment: с куковой библиотекой чего плохо - куки все время летают туда-сюда, а тут скорее именно localstorage (с fallback на куки)